# How does overload work in Kotlin without default params

Tags: kotlin, overloading

I have a function that may take one or two parameters. In Java I would simply overload:

```
public myMethod( Cat cat, Dog dog){…}

public myMethod( Cat cat){…}
```

I understood that Kotlin has default params that would make overloading unnecessary. But these are objects for which I really know no default. So how do I proceed? And I don’t want to claim it’s nullable just for the sake of making null the default value. Any options I’m not seeing?

basically I don't want this

```
fun myMethod(cat:Cat, dog:Dog?=null) //it's never really nullable so don't want to pretend
```

Comment: Does your Cat & Dog inherit from same parent?

Comment: If you're asking how you do overloads in Kotlin, the answer is: the same as in Java.  As for other options: there's often _some_ default value you can use, whether it's null or 0 or -1 or a named constant or whatever — or if there's not, then the two cases are probably sufficiently different as to justify separate overloads.

Comment: "it's never really nullable so don't want to pretend" what do you mean by that? So, there is a default value you assign along the way?

Answer (score 2):

> I understood that Kotlin has default params that would make overloading unnecessary.

They don't; they make a specific (and very common in Java) usage of overloading unnecessary. *If* in Java you'd write

```
public myMethod(Cat cat){
    myMethod(cat, new Dog(...)) // or myMethod(cat, null)
}
```

then in Kotlin you'd use a default argument. If you don't, then you use overloaded methods just like in Java, as mightyWOZ's answer shows.

Answer (score 1):

`Method` (or `function`) overloading in kotlin works the same way as it works in java. That is you can specify multiple `functions` with same name but with different signature.

From [Kotlin language specification](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlin-spec/#overload-resolution)

> Kotlin supports function overloading, ***that is, the ability for several
>   functions of the same name to coexist in the same scope***, with the
>   compiler picking the most suitable one when such a function is called.

So in your case if you don't want to use `default` `parameters`, ***then you can specify two different `functions` with same name but with different `arguments`.***

So your java code can be converted to kotlin as.

```
fun myMethod(cat: Cat, dog: Dog){…}
fun myMethod(cat: Cat){…}
```

And you can call the `overloaded` `functions` as

```
var dog = Dog()
var cat = Cat()
myMethod(dog,cat)
myMethod(cat)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think as `Dog` is nullable in your in your Java method `public myMethod( Cat cat){…}`. There is no dog so it can be treated as `null`, since it doesn't exist. Then just check if it is `null` in kotlin and proceed as if it never was there.

Comment: Thanks for replying but it looks like you missed the question. How do I properly do the overload in Kotlin? Is there a proper idiomatic Kotlin way of doing it?

Comment: This is only true if `myMethod(cat)` is supposed to do exactly the same thing as `myMethod(cat, null)`. You could be mutating something with a nullable Dog, in which case passing null should cause a different behavior than passing no Dog at all.

Answer (score 0):

First let's see what the [Kotlin Language Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-docs.pdf) says:

> Prefer declaring functions with default parameter values to declaring
>   overloaded functions.

---

> And I don’t want to claim it’s nullable just for the sake of making
>   null the default value.

Then don't. So, you have to have some way of initializing `dog`.
You can specifiy a default value for dog right in the parameter list.

```
fun myMethod(cat: Cat, dog: Dog = Dog(...)) { 
     // ...
}
```

If you don't have a way of initializing `dog` when calling `myMethod`, it is not such a bad idea (as you might think) to make the parameter nullable. `null` means the value is absent and this is exactly the case.

```
fun myMethod(cat: Cat, dog: Dog? = null) {
    // handle nullable dog
}
```

Comment: I think the advice should really say "Prefer declaring functions with default parameter values to declaring overloaded functions _to emulate default parameters_" (that's what the "bad example" `fun foo() = foo("a")` there does), but that's hardly the only use of overloads.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov sounds reasonable. still, I think `myMethod(cat: Cat)` and the one with the dog parameter too share some code. So why not put them in one function? Why would a nullable parameter be worse than another overload with the parameter missing?

Comment: If they do, then yes. OTOH, if you end up with `if (dog != null) { do one thing } else { do something different }` then overloading makes sense.